# Best Way to Track Logs

Tags: civicrm.settings.php, logging

I am running into two separate issues that I need to address with logging.

I am having trouble with the MailChimp extension and turned on logging and I do not know the best way to get the logs.

I am having an upgrade fail and I need to know where the logging for this.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you install https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer - it provides a way to view the main CiviCRM configandlog from within the CiviCRM GUI. Look for it under Manage Extensions -> Add New.